# how to use mouse event to get out loop in opencv using setmousecallback

Tags: opencv

I am using openCV's setmousecallback() function to break from the for while loop(of webcam video frames) as soon as user presses mouse right click..
But the program is getting hang instead. Someone can help me please..

Below is the code i am using, please pardon me for any compilation error

```
//mouse callback funtion
void getMouseLoc(int event, int xCor, int yCor, int flags, void* userInput)
{
Point3_<int> *mouseInputs = (Point3_<int>*)userInput;
mouseInputs->x= xCor;
mouseInputs->y = yCor;
mouseInputs->z = event;
}

// for loop
for( ; ; )
{
camera >> frame;
imshow("averageFrame", aver`enter code here`ageFrame);
setMouseCallback("averageFrame", getMouseLoc, &mouseInputs);
if( mouseInputs.z == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN)
{
cout << "topmost cordinates of ROI selected by user" << endl;
count << mouseInputs.x << " and " << mouseInputs.y << endl;
break;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks Soner for formatting the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//mouse callback function
void getMouseLoc(int event, int xCor, int yCor, int flags, void* userInput)
{
    Point3_<int> *mouseInputs = (Point3_<int>*)userInput;
    mouseInputs->x= xCor;
    mouseInputs->y = yCor;
    mouseInputs->z = event;
}

// this does not have to be inside the loop, once is enough:        
Point3_<int> mouseInputs;
setMouseCallback("averageFrame", getMouseLoc, &mouseInputs);

// for loop
for( ; ; )
{
    camera >> frame;
    imshow("averageFrame", aver`enter code here`ageFrame);

    // you're  missing a call to waitKey(), else your image won't get updated !!
    int k = waitKey(40);
    if ( k == 27 ) break; // esc pressed.

    if( mouseInputs.z == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        cout << "topmost cordinates of ROI selected by user" << endl;
        count << mouseInputs.x << " and " << mouseInputs.y << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, you want to make sure, that your 2nd point is bottom/right to the 1st clicked point. else you will get invalid ROI's

Comment: actually point clicked will be center of ROI. one thing remains why call to waitKey() is required to update image.. short explanation will also do.. thanks